# How to define function binding inside GStringTemplateEngine template?

Tags: templates, groovy, closures

I would like to define a function to be used in templates for GStringTemplateEngine.
I tried to use binding like that:

```
import groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine

def prettify = {
 return "***${it}***"
}
def var = "test"

def f = new File('index.tpl')
engine = new GStringTemplateEngine()
tpl = engine.createTemplate(f).make([
    "var": var,
    "prettify": prettify
])
print tpl.toString()
```

index.tpl:

```
Var: ${var}
Prettified: <% print prettify(var) %>
```

It throws an exception:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.tmp.templates.GStringTemplateScript1.prettify() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [test]
Possible solutions: notify(), printf(java.lang.String, [Ljava.lang.Object;), printf(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), printf(java.lang.String, [Ljava.lang.Object;), identity(groovy.lang.Closure), printf(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)
```

But it's not working. Looks like the template engine casts closures in bindings to boolean. How do I do it? Or probably I should pick another template engine?

Comment: Could you pst an example of index.tpl? Your code should work, so it's likely more an issue of how you're invoking it in the template.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I added the template code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing your index.tpl into:

```
Var: ${var}
Prettified: <% print prettify.call(var) %>
```

Will result in:

```
***test***Var: test
Prettified:
```

If you change your index.tpl into:

```
Var: ${var}
Prettified: ${prettify.call(var)}
```

The output is:

```
Var: test
Prettified: ***test***
```